# android.gesture.GestureOverlayView gesture disappear instantly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, gesture

This is my source code of signature.xml

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
 android:id="@+id/signature" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="120dip"
 android:gestureStrokeWidth="2" android:gestureColor="#000000"
 android:background="#ffffff" android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
 android:fadeOffset="10000" android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true">
 </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

Related java code :

```
public class Signature extends LinearLayout {
public Signature(final Context context){
super(context); 
inflate(context, R.layout.signature, this); 
GestureOverlayView overlayView= (GestureOverlayView)   findViewById(R.id.signature);
```

The issue is that the gesture stroke disappears instantly. Is this good code? Can I use Gesture in LinearLayout?

Comment: what do you mean by dissapears instantly? r u suggesting that multiple strokes dont work?or u want the signature to stay on screen longer?